# Can only see documents which I upload to SharePoint online Library || Cannot see the documents uploaded by others in the same library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, sharepoint-permissions

I can only see documents which I upload to the SharePoint Library, There are other users who have uploaded documents in there but I can't see those - but at the same time other users can see only documents uploaded by them and not the ones uploaded by me, All the users in there have edit permissions for the library.

we want all the users to see all the documents uploaded in there who has the permissions for that library irrespective of the user uploading by their own or others who have the same level permissions for the library.

Any help will be appreciated asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue with this - There was a problem with the Documents not checked in by other users, After the Check in that fixed it. Thank you all for your support! Appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check below things which might be causing this issue:

**Item-level permissions**:

Check if there are any item/document level permissions applied to documents by default (maybe by using any flow/workflow).

**Checked out files**:

Check if documents are checked out by default. If yes, user needs to check-in/publish the documents so that other users can see them.

**Filtering in view**:

Check if there are any filters applied to library view based on current logged in user probably using `[Me]`.

Answer (score 0):

can you please check the list view that applied any filters like [created by] = [Me].

Answer (score 0):

Also check if the documents are checked out. That could also be the case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Checking the list view filter like Shahul said, you can directly edit current view like this:

[image]

Check the filter part where may have been configured. The default setting shall be like below.

[image]

2. If versioning have been enabled and minor version has been enabled, have a check if all the files have been published as major version. There are draft item security settings which may cause similar issue:
   [image]